# Insert formula if blank if next cell in row within range, but freeze data from previous cell/ remove formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, macros, range

I have some users that are manually entering data from one excel generated from a reporting system and entering in that data into hundreds of cells per day. The format of the report generated excel is static, so I want to map that data to the cells they are entering. The problem is the data is a moving target.

I want the formula (something like ='data'B2) to be entered into the first cell in the range if it is blank. When it is run the next time, if there is data in the first cell in the row, it needs to freeze that data/ remove the formula, and enter the formula in the next empty cell in that row. Any help would be appreciated!

It would look something like this pseudo code wise:

```
Range = a1-a9
If cell a1 blank then = Data sheet a1
If not blank then freeze cell data/ remove formula and enter formula = Data sheet a1
```

(and so on if necessary (unless better code))

until all cells in range are full

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of an example you are referring to? That would help make it clear for anyone attempting to help you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the best I can do with what you've outlined:

```
Sub test()
Dim src As Worksheet
Set src = Sheets("Sheet3")
Dim dest As Worksheet
Set dest = Sheets("Sheet5")
Dim n As Long
Dim j As Integer
j = dest.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1


For i = 1 To j
    If dest.Cells(i, 1) = "" Then
        dest.Cells(i, 1).Formula = "=Sheet3!A1"
        Else:  n = dest.Cells(i, 1)
        dest.Cells(i, 1) = n
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

If `A1` is blank, it will do `A1:A2` otherwise it's fine. Change as needed.